# facebook authentication, why I am getting a different login window

Tags: facebook-graph-api, authentication, facebook

I followed the instruction on this page (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) to add facebook authentication on my web site.

I manage to get it work however, the request for permission window is not the same. the first one is how it's supposed to look like. the second one is what I have.

here's the code i use.

"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id={0}& redirect_uri={1}{2}&scope=email,user_photos,publish_stream";

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the new dialog - if you want to disable that for some reason there's an option in the app settings for 'enabled enhanced auth dialog' - turn it off

Comment: I have it enabled without knowing what that for. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are using the right id from your facebook app? You can find this id here: https://developers.facebook.com/apps

Comment: yes, my ID is correct, those {0}, {1}, {2} are placeholders, they are replaced by real values I set in the web.config file.  my authentication works. but instead having log in button, I should have allow button on the page.